# Disable Kafka Warnings for Spark Streaming Application

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, suppress-warnings, spark-streaming-kafka

I use Spark Structured Streaming (pyspark) to read data from Kafka topic. It works well but when I open executors stderr my whole log page is WARN from Kafka saying that
`kafkadataconsumer is not running in uninterruptiblethread. it may hang when kafkadataconsumer's methods are interrupted because of kafka-1894`. How can I disable this warning or maybe fix consumer?

Spark: 3.1.1 with org.apache.spark:spark-sql-kafka-0-10_2.12:3.1.2

I tried several options but afaik kafka consumer doesn't know that it runs within some spark application so it is useless trying to set `sparkContext.setLogLevel`. The most recent try was with something like this:

```
logger = spark._jvm.org.apache.log4j
logger.LogManager.getLogger("org.apache.kafka").setLevel(logger.Level.ERROR)
```

But it doesn't work :(

P.S. Yeah, I know that it is just warning and warning is not an error, but I think one executor generates a nearly 2k rows per second of these warnings so you can't find a useful prints. You either scroll for a really long time or waiting for log file to be loaded. So its kinda frustrating

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by adding two lines at the end of default log4j.properties file

```
log4j.logger.org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer=ERROR
log4j.additivity.org.apache.spark.sql.kafka010.consumer.KafkaDataConsumer=false
```

Then just add this file to my application and set this spark config variable `--conf "spark.executor.extraJavaOptions=-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///some_path/log4j.properties"`